# Gmail how to filter calendar events into label / star / important

Tags: gmail, calendar

I just missed an important meeting because of Gmail calendar, ... the first invite email showed up in my inbox and I accepted and got the event to show in my calendar (so far so good).

Without my knowledge the organiser updated the time and the event update email did not show in inbox but was hidden in updates folder (with 10k other emails). Also the event did not automatically update with the new time.

Now I am researching working filters to apply in GMAIL to make sure I am catching all calendar events from Gmail / OL and Airlines / Europcar etc to make them show up in inbox.

Web search was semi-successfull, I have not found yet a filter that catches all my calendar events.

Someone here must have done this before :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this Google Support article today on [Filter calendar responses from your Gmail inbox](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/11387073?hl=en#zippy=%2Clearn-how).

> 1. Open Gmail.
> 2. In the search box at the top, click Show search options
> 3. In the **To** field, enter your email address.
> 4. Next to **Has the words**, enter **invite.ics OR invite.vcs**.
> 5. Check the Has attachment box.
> 6. Click **Create filter**.
> 7. Check the set the filter rules you'd like (label, skip inbox, etc)
> 8. Click Create filter.

Answer (score 0):

After toying around it seems this filter catches all my events so far:

**"*.ics" AND has:attachment AND ("(GMT" OR "Invitation:" OR "updated" OR "invited" OR "accepted" OR "declined"))**

In the filter rule set: **star (moves it to inbox), important, never spam, and move to label i.e. "calendar events".**

Still testing though and open for feedback on improved versions.

Comment: unfortunately that does not catch everything

Comment: *.ics" AND has:attachment  - catches all invites and updates, but not accept and decline